# Submit form on same page based on different submit buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I have three buttons on a page and I want to submit that form on the same page, depending to the button press, corresponding query will run. But there are some problem with the script.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or
die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db('easy_excel', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

if ($_POST['submit'] =='delete_aabb') 
{
$query ='DELETE FROM aabb';
mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
echo 'All Data from aabb Deleted succecfully!';
}
elseif ($_POST['submit'] =='delete_bbcc') {
$query ='DELETE FROM bbcc';
mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
echo 'All Data from bbcc Deleted succecfully!';
}
elseif ($_POST['submit'] =='show_bbcc') {
$query = 'SELECT
name
FROM  bbcc';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

echo '<table border="1">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($row as $value) {
echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Say My Name</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete_aabb" />
</tr>

<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete_bbcc" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="show_bbcc" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This script is not running. Please help me.

Comment: diff submit buttons should be with diff names i.e. name=submit1, name=submit2, then test with `if(isset($_POST['submit1']))`, `if(isset($_POST['submit2']))`

Comment: @RoyalBg, you can have many submit buttons with the same name and different value.

Comment: @invisal  I guess, like any other field, but this way you need more testing, because first you need to test if the submit name is even set, then its value, otherwise a NOTICE will be present

Comment: i tried this.. name=submit1, name=submit2, then test with if(isset($_POST['submit1'])), if(isset($_POST['submit2']))           But error is still here....

Comment: @RoyalBg, I am not saying it is the best solution, just stated that it is possible.

Comment: @vick, saying there is error does not help. You need to tell what is the error message.

Comment: @invisal yep, ok :) thank for making it clear. vick what error

Comment: Error is SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: submit in G:\wamp\www\for delete duplicate\one_page_test.php on line 8

Comment: you haven't checked if submit was set

Comment: @Class dear how can i check if submit was set.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` also you might want to add the test at the top of the page before db connect and last brace at the end of script.

Comment: @Class i at the top i tried it "if(isset($_POST['submit']))"           Now other error is            ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in G:\wamp\www\for delete duplicate\one_page_test.php on line 88

Comment: @vick did you add a `{` after the `isset` and `}` before `?>` ?

Comment: @vick use some IDE that will tell you which braces are not closed

Comment: @Class yes i add {} But i added at wrong place...now as you told "before ?>"  i did it...and now my script is running well...Thanks CLASS. again Thank you for help me.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use ***MySQLi*** instead of deprecated ***MySQL***. And I think you're referring to the `isset()` function.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Say My Name</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION USING MYSQLi */

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","easy_excel");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['delete_aabb'])) /* IF DELETE_AABB IS CLICKED */
{
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM aabb");
echo 'All Data from aabb Deleted succecfully!';
}
else if (isset($_POST['delete_bbcc'])) { /* IF DELETE_BBCC IS CLICKED */
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM bbcc");
echo 'All Data from bbcc Deleted succecfully!';
}
else if (isset($_POST['show_bbcc'])) { /* IF SHOW_BBCC IS CLICKED */
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name FROM bbcc");

echo '<table border="1">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($row as $value) {
echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete_aabb" name="delete_aabb"/>
</tr>

<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="delete_bbcc" name="delete_bbcc"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="show_bbcc" name="show_bbcc"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```